# Appending multiple values to an xml file in python. Is there a better way to do it than %s?

Tags: python, fabric

I am converting NAnt deployment to Fabric, and I encounter an xml template file that uses @ to append values. the below is the snippet of the template

```
<couchbase>
    <servers bucket="@Deploy.Couchbase.GameBucket.Name@" bucketPassword="@Deploy.Couchbase.GameBucket.Password@">
      @Deploy.Couchbase.GameBucket.Uris@
    </servers>
    <socketPool minPoolSize="50" maxPoolSize="250" queueTimeout="00:00:00.250" />
  </couchbase>
  <couchbaseCluster>
    <servers username="@Deploy.Couchbase.Administrator.Username@" password="@Deploy.Couchbase.Administrator.Password@">
      @Deploy.Couchbase.GameBucket.Uris@
    </servers>
  </couchbaseCluster>
  <couchbaseSession>
    <servers bucket="@Deploy.Couchbase.SessionBucket.Name@" bucketPassword="@Deploy.Couchbase.SessionBucket.Password@">
      @Deploy.Couchbase.SessionBucket.Uris@
    </servers>
  </couchbaseSession>
```

after appending the values, it should look like this:

```
<couchbase>
    <servers bucket="Game" bucketPassword="">
      <add uri="http://couchbase.chubi.staging1:8091/pools" />
      <add uri="http://couchbase.chubi.staging2:8091/pools" />
      <add uri="http://couchbase.chubi.staging3:8091/pools" />
    </servers>
  </couchbase>
  <couchbaseCluster>
    <servers username="dreamrocket" password="rocketstart">
      <add uri="http://couchbase.chubi.staging1:8091/pools" />
      <add uri="http://couchbase.chubi.staging2:8091/pools" />
      <add uri="http://couchbase.chubi.staging3:8091/pools" />
    </servers>
  </couchbaseCluster>
  <couchbaseSession>
    <servers bucket="Session" bucketPassword="">
      <add uri="http://couchbase.chubi.staging1:11212" />
      <add uri="http://couchbase.chubi.staging2:11212" />
      <add uri="http://couchbase.chubi.staging3:11212" />
    </servers>
  </couchbaseSession>
```

Is there an easy and elegant way of doing it in python than just to use %s?

Answer (score 2):

You should better use libraries like [beautiful soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) or [xml.dom](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html) that can use xml dom. It will make your task much easier. To add new nodes, xml.dom can do it with:

```
node_new = doc.createElement("node1")
node_val = node_new.setAttribute('RelativePath',value)
```

Comment: I disagree with this approach. While still correct, i would rather use string `format()` over this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use any of the million template engines out there and do NOT build it using beautiful soup/xml.dom. Its like building html using `$('<div>').append(...)` <- please don't do that either.

Do this if you want the most plug and play solution:

```
from mako.template import Template

class obj(object):
    def __init__(self, d):
        for a, b in d.items():
            if isinstance(b, (list, tuple)):
               setattr(self, a, [obj(x) if isinstance(x, dict) else x for x in b])
            else:
               setattr(self, a, obj(b) if isinstance(b, dict) else b)

Deploy = {
    'Couchbase': {
        'GameBucket': {
            'Name': 'Game',
            'Password': '',
            'Uris': '<add uri="' + '" /><add uri="'.join([
                'http://couchbase.chubi.staging1:8091/pools',
                'http://couchbase.chubi.staging2:8091/pools',
                'http://couchbase.chubi.staging3:8091/pools'
            ]) + '" />'
        },
        'Administrator': {
            'Username': 'Game',
            'Password': '',
            'Uris': '<add uri="' + '" /><add uri="'.join([
                'http://couchbase.chubi.staging1:8091/pools',
                'http://couchbase.chubi.staging2:8091/pools',
                'http://couchbase.chubi.staging3:8091/pools'
            ]) + '" />'
        },
        'SessionBucket': {
            'Name': 'Session',
            'Password': '',
            'Uris': '<add uri="' + '" /><add uri="'.join([
                'http://couchbase.chubi.staging1:8091/pools',
                'http://couchbase.chubi.staging2:8091/pools',
                'http://couchbase.chubi.staging3:8091/pools'
            ]) + '" />'
        }
    }
}
template = Template("""<couchbase>
    <servers bucket="${Deploy.Couchbase.GameBucket.Name}" bucketPassword="${Deploy.Couchbase.GameBucket.Password}">
      ${Deploy.Couchbase.GameBucket.Uris}
    </servers>
    <socketPool minPoolSize="50" maxPoolSize="250" queueTimeout="00:00:00.250" />
  </couchbase>
  <couchbaseCluster>
    <servers username="${Deploy.Couchbase.Administrator.Username}" password="${Deploy.Couchbase.Administrator.Password}">
      ${Deploy.Couchbase.GameBucket.Uris}
    </servers>
  </couchbaseCluster>
  <couchbaseSession>
    <servers bucket="${Deploy.Couchbase.SessionBucket.Name}" bucketPassword="${Deploy.Couchbase.SessionBucket.Password}">
      ${Deploy.Couchbase.SessionBucket.Uris}
    </servers>
  </couchbaseSession>
""")
print template.render(Deploy=obj(Deploy))
```

output:

```
<couchbase>
    <servers bucket="Game" bucketPassword="">
      <add uri="http://couchbase.chubi.staging1:8091/pools" /><add uri="http://couchbase.chubi.staging2:8091/pools" /><add uri="http://couchbase.chubi.staging3:8091/pools" />
    </servers>
    <socketPool minPoolSize="50" maxPoolSize="250" queueTimeout="00:00:00.250" />
  </couchbase>
  <couchbaseCluster>
    <servers username="Game" password="">
      <add uri="http://couchbase.chubi.staging1:8091/pools" /><add uri="http://couchbase.chubi.staging2:8091/pools" /><add uri="http://couchbase.chubi.staging3:8091/pools" />
    </servers>
  </couchbaseCluster>
  <couchbaseSession>
    <servers bucket="Session" bucketPassword="">
      <add uri="http://couchbase.chubi.staging1:8091/pools" /><add uri="http://couchbase.chubi.staging2:8091/pools" /><add uri="http://couchbase.chubi.staging3:8091/pools" />
    </servers>
  </couchbaseSession>
```

By far the cleanest solution would be changing things around a tiny bit:

```
from mako.template import Template

class obj(object):
    def __init__(self, d):
        for a, b in d.items():
            if isinstance(b, (list, tuple)):
               setattr(self, a, [obj(x) if isinstance(x, dict) else x for x in b])
            else:
               setattr(self, a, obj(b) if isinstance(b, dict) else b)

Deploy = {
    'Couchbase': {
        'GameBucket': {
            'Name': 'Game',
            'Password': '',
            'Uris': [
                'http://couchbase.chubi.staging1:8091/pools',
                'http://couchbase.chubi.staging2:8091/pools',
                'http://couchbase.chubi.staging3:8091/pools'
            ]
        },
        'Administrator': {
            'Username': 'Game',
            'Password': '',
            'Uris': [
                'http://couchbase.chubi.staging1:8091/pools',
                'http://couchbase.chubi.staging2:8091/pools',
                'http://couchbase.chubi.staging3:8091/pools'
            ]
        },
        'SessionBucket': {
            'Name': 'Session',
            'Password': '',
            'Uris': [
                'http://couchbase.chubi.staging1:8091/pools',
                'http://couchbase.chubi.staging2:8091/pools',
                'http://couchbase.chubi.staging3:8091/pools'
            ]
        }
    }
}
template = Template("""<couchbase>
  <servers bucket="${Deploy.Couchbase.GameBucket.Name}" bucketPassword="${Deploy.Couchbase.GameBucket.Password}">
  % for url in Deploy.Couchbase.GameBucket.Uris:
    <add uri="${url}" />
  % endfor
  </servers>
  <socketPool minPoolSize="50" maxPoolSize="250" queueTimeout="00:00:00.250" />
</couchbase>
<couchbaseCluster>
  <servers username="${Deploy.Couchbase.Administrator.Username}" password="${Deploy.Couchbase.Administrator.Password}">
  % for url in Deploy.Couchbase.GameBucket.Uris:
    <add uri="${url}" />
  % endfor
  </servers>
</couchbaseCluster>
<couchbaseSession>
  <servers bucket="${Deploy.Couchbase.SessionBucket.Name}" bucketPassword="${Deploy.Couchbase.SessionBucket.Password}">
  % for url in Deploy.Couchbase.GameBucket.Uris:
    <add uri="${url}" />
  % endfor
  </servers>
</couchbaseSession>""")
print template.render(Deploy=obj(Deploy))
```

output:

```
<couchbase>
  <servers bucket="Game" bucketPassword="">
    <add uri="http://couchbase.chubi.staging1:8091/pools" />
    <add uri="http://couchbase.chubi.staging2:8091/pools" />
    <add uri="http://couchbase.chubi.staging3:8091/pools" />
  </servers>
  <socketPool minPoolSize="50" maxPoolSize="250" queueTimeout="00:00:00.250" />
</couchbase>
<couchbaseCluster>
  <servers username="Game" password="">
    <add uri="http://couchbase.chubi.staging1:8091/pools" />
    <add uri="http://couchbase.chubi.staging2:8091/pools" />
    <add uri="http://couchbase.chubi.staging3:8091/pools" />
  </servers>
</couchbaseCluster>
<couchbaseSession>
  <servers bucket="Session" bucketPassword="">
    <add uri="http://couchbase.chubi.staging1:8091/pools" />
    <add uri="http://couchbase.chubi.staging2:8091/pools" />
    <add uri="http://couchbase.chubi.staging3:8091/pools" />
  </servers>
</couchbaseSession>
```

If you have it in a template, and believe me there is no real difference if you're using `Mako` or `Jinja2` or `django templates` is whatever you feel most comfortable with, you can get a great birds eye view of what it generates. If you create it using xml dom objects, theres no telling what the heck that does at a glance. Its all about `READABILITY` not about how clever you think you are for making what should have been 40 lines into 10 and not having a damn idea what it does 2 weeks from now when you come back to make a minor adjustment.

Also i should add; the class i have `obj` was just there so i didnt have to change your existing structure. I really do hope its an object.

---

HERE BE DRAGONS.......

```
from lxml import etree

Deploy = {
    'Couchbase': {
        'GameBucket': {
            'Name': 'Game',
            'Password': '',
            'Uris': [
                'http://couchbase.chubi.staging1:8091/pools',
                'http://couchbase.chubi.staging2:8091/pools',
                'http://couchbase.chubi.staging3:8091/pools'
            ]
        },
        'Administrator': {
            'Username': 'Game',
            'Password': '',
            'Uris': [
                'http://couchbase.chubi.staging1:8091/pools',
                'http://couchbase.chubi.staging2:8091/pools',
                'http://couchbase.chubi.staging3:8091/pools'
            ]
        },
        'SessionBucket': {
            'Name': 'Session',
            'Password': '',
            'Uris': [
                'http://couchbase.chubi.staging1:8091/pools',
                'http://couchbase.chubi.staging2:8091/pools',
                'http://couchbase.chubi.staging3:8091/pools'
            ]
        }
    }
}

root = etree.Element("root")

couchbase = etree.Element("couchbase")
servers = etree.Element(
    "servers",
    bucket=Deploy['Couchbase']['GameBucket']['Name'],
    bucketPassword=Deploy['Couchbase']['GameBucket']['Password']
)

for url in Deploy['Couchbase']['GameBucket']['Uris']:
    servers.append(etree.Element("add", uri=url))

servers.append(
    etree.Element(
        "socketPool",
        minPoolSize="50",
        maxPoolSize="250",
        queueTimeout="00:00:00.250"
    )
)


couchbase.append(servers)

print etree.tostring(couchbase, pretty_print=True)
```

you would need to still do the other two.. PLEASE DONT DO THIS!!! Its hard on the eyes. I feel pretty dirty just showing this example of WHAT NOT TO DO!!!

---

Comment: *cough* input sanitizing *cough*

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos: Its inside a fabric script. I doubt the malicious users of the web would have anything to do here..

Comment: Still, this will explode if any of the input items have any double quotes.

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos Fine, fair enough. to all the `${...}` replace with `${... | u}`

Comment: Is there any way to use other markers instead of ${}? Because I have other areas of the XML that has the ${} and needs to be kept that way after the values are appended

Comment: @MosesLiaoGZ as far as i know, no. But like i mentioned before there are a lot of options when it comes to `different` template engines. I personally like django's, just because i like `mustache` and it reminds me a lot of it.

Comment: But i should add: according to what ive heard (again ive never personally benchmarked it) its slow (the django templating engine). If youre generating a file once a second, its not going to make that much of a difference anyway. If you're generating 10,000 different pages a second, maybe django templating engine is not for you. You've been warned.

Comment: it is for fabric deployment so i think it is not going to make much of a difference unless I am deploying into 10,000 servers within a second :)

Comment: @MosesLiaoGZ i figured. I just wanted to clarify it before someone comes and says how slow the template engine is.